# Sending the value of the cookie across java classes - Android

Tags: java, android, cookies

I want to know how the value of the session cookie can be sent from one class to another in android?

This is my Cookie Activity from which I want to get the value of cookie in another class:

```
class MyCookieStore implements CookieStore {

String TAG = "Cookie";
String cookie_object = null;
/*
 * The memory storage of the cookies
 */
private Map<URI, List<HttpCookie>> mapCookies = new HashMap<URI, List<HttpCookie>>();
/*
 * The instance of the shared preferences
 */
private final SharedPreferences spePreferences;

/*
 * @see java.net.CookieStore#add(java.net.URI, java.net.HttpCookie)
 */
public void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {

    System.out.println("add");
    System.out.println(cookie.toString());

    List<HttpCookie> cookies = mapCookies.get(uri);
    if (cookies == null) {
        cookies = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
        mapCookies.put(uri, cookies);
    }
    cookies.add(cookie);

    SharedPreferences.Editor ediWriter = spePreferences.edit();
    HashSet<String> setCookies = new HashSet<String>();
    setCookies.add(cookie.toString());

    Log.d(TAG,cookie.toString());
    cookie_object = cookie.toString();
    Log.d("Cookie object",cookie_object);

    ediWriter.putStringSet(uri.toString(), spePreferences.getStringSet(uri.toString(), setCookies));
    ediWriter.commit();



}

/*
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param  ctxContext the context of the Activity
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MyCookieStore(Context ctxContext) {

    spePreferences = ctxContext.getSharedPreferences("CookiePrefsFile", 0);
    Map<String, ?> prefsMap = spePreferences.getAll();

    for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : prefsMap.entrySet()) {

        for (String strCookie : (HashSet<String>) entry.getValue()) {

            if (!mapCookies.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {

                List<HttpCookie> lstCookies = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
                lstCookies.addAll(HttpCookie.parse(strCookie));

                try {

                    mapCookies.put(new URI(entry.getKey()), lstCookies);

                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            } else {

                List<HttpCookie> lstCookies = mapCookies.get(entry.getKey());
                lstCookies.addAll(HttpCookie.parse(strCookie));

                try {

                    mapCookies.put(new URI(entry.getKey()), lstCookies);
                    Log.d(TAG, lstCookies.toString());

                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + strCookie);

        }

    }

}

/*
 * @see java.net.CookieStore#get(java.net.URI)
 */
public List<HttpCookie> get(URI uri) {

    List<HttpCookie> lstCookies = mapCookies.get(uri);

    if (lstCookies == null)
        mapCookies.put(uri, new ArrayList<HttpCookie>());

    return mapCookies.get(uri);

}

/*
 * @see java.net.CookieStore#removeAll()
 */
public boolean removeAll() {

    mapCookies.clear();
    return true;

}

/*
 * @see java.net.CookieStore#getCookies()
 */
public List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {

    Collection<List<HttpCookie>> values = mapCookies.values();

    List<HttpCookie> result = new ArrayList<HttpCookie>();
    for (List<HttpCookie> value : values) {
        result.addAll(value);
    }

    return result;

}

/*
 * @see java.net.CookieStore#getURIs()
 */
public List<URI> getURIs() {

    Set<URI> keys = mapCookies.keySet();
    return new ArrayList<URI>(keys);

}

/*
 * @see java.net.CookieStore#remove(java.net.URI, java.net.HttpCookie)
 */
public boolean remove(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {

    List<HttpCookie> lstCookies = mapCookies.get(uri);

    if (lstCookies == null)
        return false;

    return lstCookies.remove(cookie);

}

}
```

I want to know how to export the cookie.toString() to another java class in the android app.

Comment: That doesn't look like an Activity class.  If you simply want to send some String data to another Activity, you can create a Bundle to hold the data and pass the Bundle to the new Activity via an Intent.

Comment: This is not an activity class. It is just a java class. That's why bundles and intents cannot be used.

Comment: Do you want to send the data back to the Activity which you are calling..?

Comment: No I don't want to. I just want to send the data to another class.